# CSS border and padding not working in IE 8 + 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following DOM and CSS:

```
var tableRow = jQuery(
    jQuery('<tr/>')
        .addClass('tr_class')
        .append(
            jQuery('<h3/>')
                .text('Title')
                .addClass('first_class second_class')
        )
).appendTo(table);


.tr_class{
    padding: 0px 0px 2px 5px;          /*not working*/
    display: block;                    /*not working*/
}


h3.first_class {
    font-weight: bold;                /*working*/
}


h3.second_class {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5f7836; /*not working*/
    padding: 3px;                     /*not working*/
    display: block;                   /*not working*/
    font-size: 11px;                  /*working*/
}
```

In IE8 + 9, several of my CSS rules are not working.

`border`, `padding` and `display`.

Can anyone explain why this might be?

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the rendered HTML.

**UPDATE**

I appreciate all of the comments and suggestions, I'm going to look into fixing my mark up...

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

You were all correct! My horrendous mark up was the culprit here. Everyone's input was much appreciated!

Comment: Show us your HTML aswell.

Comment: just to let you know : `padding` and `display` are invalid properties for `tr`

Comment: I added a jsfiddle @Complexity

Comment: Hmm, funnily enough border bottom is working for me in Chrome, but some of the other elements you say are working are not. I have started a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/30jgfvvz/ but I have had to guess some of your other markup.

Comment: @Iharby: remove invalid commented code from css .. then other styles will work as well

Comment: and according to this fiddle .. `h3` is directly going in `<tr>` whichis wrong markup

Comment: @Era of course, it should be '/* */' for comments after css. Yeah I just threw down some basic table html without having seen OP markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not only IE 8+ issue but it won't work in any browser.

You can't have padding in table rows. Instead you need to add the padding styles in your `td`.

And I can't see that you're appending any `td` in your code so I could modify that.

Thus, ensure to put padding styles in your `td` instead of `tr`.

And just be ensure to put `td` in your `tr` and do the rest things like border and anything you want on it.

Answer (score 2):

- Several css properties, `padding` and `border` among them, are invalid when applied to `tr` elements
- You are nesting an `h3` directly under a `tr`, which is invalid HTML. `tr` elements may only directly contain `th` or `td`.

Answer (score 1):

IE 8+ use css style: border, padding and display, likely problem in you html structure.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought is that you have the HTML tags wrong.  It is

```
<tr> and <h3> for starting a tag, and </tr> and </h3> for closing/ending a tag.
```

The second is the sytnax of the jQuery you are using.  Try the more modern syntax, such as:

```
$('tr') instead of JQuery('<tr>').
```

Comment: $('tr') is not the same as $('<tr>'). The first selects existing tr elements in the DOM, the second creates a jQuery object containing a new tr element.

Comment: Good point, ChrisV - I completely overlooked that! :-)  To me, it is not entirely clear in the OP's question that he wants to add to existing tags or create them on-the-fly.

Comment: @JimmPratt it's pretty clear I'm creating them. $('<tr/>') creates elements, it doesn't select them.

Comment: <tr/> was still wrong, in my opinion.  The slash is (according to the W3C standards that I understand) meant to precede the tag name, not follow it.