# Why do padding and display CSS attributes work on tr elements in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431007/css-border-and-padding-not-working-in-ie-8-9) yesterday.

My `padding` and `display` CSS attributes were not taking effect on a `tr` element in IE. I thought it was an IE bug but it was my terrible mark up which was to blame.

Many people pointed out that `padding` and `display` are invalid CSS attributes for `tr` elements.

Why then, do they work in Chrome?

If I put the follwoing CSS on a `tr` element, the CSS takes effect.

```
    tr{ 
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

Is this a bug with Chrome or perhaps is the browser doing it's best to make sense of terribly written CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display` property can be applied to a `tr`, but in order for a `tr` to behave like a table row it needs to be `display: table-row`. Changing the display value will prevent it from working as expected and cause unintended (but [consistent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes)) side effects to the table layout. Namely, an anonymous table row (and cell) will be created around the element within the table, and the element itself will be laid out differently.

The `padding` property indeed does not apply to table rows; you can see this in the [definition given by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties):

> *Applies to:*     all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column

However, what you're doing here is turning the `tr` into a block box, which obviously supports padding, and that is how Chrome is able to render both properties. If you did not change its `display`, then the padding should not apply. If it did, then *that* would be a bug.

If IE fails to render the element as a block box, then that is likely a bug too, owing perhaps to poor implementation of anonymous table objects.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the question you linked, Its true as said by the accepted answer

> This is not only IE 8+ issue but it won't work in any browser.
>
> You can't have padding in table rows. Instead you need to add the
>   padding styles in your td.
>
> And I can't see that you're appending any td in your code so I could
>   modify that.
>
> Thus, ensure to put padding styles in your td instead of tr.
>
> And just be ensure to put td in your tr and do the rest things like
>   border and anything you want on it.

Now as written in this question, you tr, i.e:

```
tr{ 
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

is no more a `table-row`, since it is displayed as a block using `css`(and this is possible with the display property), and thus must be able to have padding, so there is no issue

Comment: So the `display:block` renders the `tr` no longer a `tr`? I didn't know that. Very interesting!

Answer (score -1):

You can't style the TR themselves, but you can give to a TD inside a TR mark a style, like this :

```
tr td {padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom:10px}
```

Then, you can do :

```
tr td:first-child {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

tr td:last-child {
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```